# Why provide database name when starting postgresql base backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

According to the postgresql 8 manual, before starting a base backup (i.e. copying the files out of the data directory), you need to issue a command like this:

```
psql -d DATABASENAME -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('label');
```

But, since the postgresql files in the data directory contain ALL databases held by postgresql, what is the point of specifying DATABASENAME?  (eg: mydb).  Is it equally effecting to just use template0 as the databasename?

Comment: Have you tried to use `psql` without providing DB name? Usually all RDBMS backup single databases instead of the whole server.

Comment: McNets: ProgreSQL seems to be different (unless a pgsql explains otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Because you must connect to a specific DB in all cases. In psql if you don't specify a database it tries to connect, at least in *nix (any Unix like OS), to a database with the same name as the user in the operating system. Not sure Windows, but I would think it probably behaves the same.

The authentication mechanism doesn't know, or care, what operation you are about to do. It just needs to verify:

- Does the user exist?
- Did we get proper password for the user (unless you are setup with trust connections)?
- Is the user trying to connect to a database that exists and it has rights to connect?

Comment: I can connect to template1 without specifying a username/password, or my own MyDB without a username./password.  I just wondered why an operation working at the cluster level would need DB level authentication

Comment: _I can connect to template1 without specifying a username/password_ - Possibly _trust_ authentication is allowed in pg_hba.conf, which is a really bad practice. Your own DB is likely using ident; a user can connect to his own DB without a password. What you need to keep in mind is not the operation you are trying to do, but the fact that any and all connections require you to connect to a specific DB.